# Phone directory in iOS

Tags: ios, ios5, xml-parsing

I am creating a IOS phone directory app. I am trying to download a XML file from a url. This XML file will then be used to populate the directory app with phone numbers, names and identifications of all the people in the directory. I'm new to IOS development and I'm looking for any information or assistance on where to get started on how to parse the XML file.

Comment: Just wondering if you have a choice as to whether you deal with XML or JSON.  If you do, JSON is a better choice IMO.  I have used (and still use) both and dealing with JSON much easier for me.

Answer (score 1):

What is included with Cocoa is [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsxmlparser), and you can download the source code imageMap. There are also other third party libraries such as `TouchXML` and `TBXML`. Although in my experience TouchXML has some memory leaks issues that can create a lot of problems. And the one that has given me the fastest results is `TBXML` by far.

You can find a detailed article on all the available third-party parsers available here: [Best xml parser for your app](https://www.raywenderlich.com/3145-xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-choose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)

Answer (score 0):

TBXML is the way to go IMO.  I have a complete code sample if you need it.  If you post the structure of that XML file, I can modify the sample to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the webserver manually, then I would look into using JSON instead of XML. It's a bit easier to work with. If you need to use XML, the NSXML parser class works pretty well. Here is a good tutorial: http://www.xcode-tutorials.com/parsing-xml-files/

Or you could check out chapter 21 I believe of the big nerd ranch iPhone programming book for a more detailed explination.

Good Luck!